# Write a function to print (non-negative) integer numbers in full words in Clojure

Tags: clojure

```
(defn num-as-words [n]
        (let [words '("zero" "one" "two" "three" "four" 
                             "five" "six" "seven" "eight" "nine")]
          (clojure.string/join "-" 
                               (map (fn [x] (nth words (Integer. (re-find #"\d" (str x)) ))) (str n)))))
```

I've written this function called as num-as-words which takes an integer and displays it as full words, for example if you were to input (123) it would return (one-two-three).

I've done it using a map but I was wondering if there was another way of doing it? I was also wondering if there was another way to connect the words rather than clojure.string/join, I was initially using interpose but didn't like the way it was outputting, as it looked like ("one" "-" "two" "-" "three").

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
user=> (clojure.pprint/cl-format       ; formatted printing
         nil                           ; ... to a string
         "~{~R~^-~}"                   ; format (see below)
         (map                          ; map over characters
           (fn [x] (Integer. (str x))) ; convert char to integer
           (str 123)))                 ; convert number to string
"one-two-three"
```

- First, we take the input number, here hard-coded as `"123"` in the example, coerce it as a string and iterate over the resulting string's  characters thanks to `map`. For each character, we build a string containing that character and parse it as an `Integer`. Thus, we obtain a list of digits.

  More precisely, `(fn [x] ...)` is a function taking one argument. You should probably name it `char` instead (sorry), because we iterate over characters. When we evaluate `(str x)`, we obtain a string containing one char, namely `x`. For example, if the character is `\2`, the resulting string is `"2"`. The `(Integer. string)` form (notice the dot!) calls the constructor for the `Integer` class, which parse a string as an integer. To continue with our example, `(Integer. "2")` would yield the integer 2.
- We use [`cl-format`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/cl-format) to print the list of digits into a fresh string (as requested by the `false` argument). In order to do that, we specify the format as follows:
- `~{...~}` iterates over a list and executes the format inside the braces for each element.
- `~R` prints a number as an english word (1 => one, etc.)
- `~^` escapes the iteration made by `~{...~}` when there is no remaining arguments. So when we print the last digit, the part that follows `~^` is not printed.
- What follows `~^` is simply the character `-`. This is used to separate strings but we had to take care to not print a dash for all iterations of the loop, otherwise the resulting string would have ended with a dash.

If any character cannot be parsed as an Integer then the function will report an error. You might want to check first that the input really is a positive integer before converting it to a string.

Comment: (fn [x] (Integer. (str x))) 
           (str 123)))

Could you please explain what this section is doing in more detail, I'm having trouble with it

Comment: @danfs Edited with more details

Answer (score 3):

I'd implement it like this:

```
(defn num-as-words [n]
  (let [words ["zero" "one" "two" "three" "four" "five" "six" "seven" "eight" "nine"]]
    (->> (str n)
         (map #(Character/getNumericValue %))
         (map words)
         (clojure.string/join "-"))))
```

- Using vector will simplify the implementation.
- Instead of splitting number string with regular expression, you can treat it as sequence. In this case, you should use `Charactor/getNumericValue` to convert char to integer.
- You can use `->>` macro.
- Using `clojure.string/join` looks fine.
- `interpose` returns lazy sequence. That's why it returns like `("one" "-" "two"...)`. You should `apply str` to the result, `(apply str (interpose ...))` to convert it to string.

If you want to handle negative numbers, you can modify the code like this:

```
(defn num-as-words [n]
  (if (< n 0)
    (str "-" (num-as-words (- n)))
    (let [words ["zero" "one" "two" "three" "four" "five" "six" "seven" "eight" "nine"]]
      (->> (str n)
           (map #(Character/getNumericValue %))
           (map words)
           (clojure.string/join "-")))))
```

This will prepend `-` in the front. If you just want to throw an error, you can use precondition:

```
(defn num-as-words [n]
  {:pre [(<= 0 n)]}
  (let [words ["zero" "one" "two" "three" "four" "five" "six" "seven" "eight" "nine"]]
     ...
```

This will throw `AssertionError` when it receives negative number.

Comment: Thank you, do you have an idea of how I might error handle if I input a
negative number?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of replacing `(map #(nth words %))` with the simpler equivalent `(map words)`. This doesn't work for `Character/getNumericValue`, which is a Java static method, not a Clojure function.

Comment: Thank you again, for some reason when I enter 023 the out put is one-nine, why is this? Also how could I solve it?

Comment: The number begin with `0` will be treated as an octal number. octal number `027` is the same as decimal `19`. Try to enter `027` in your REPL and see what happens.